# How avoids SonarQube major issues, while using LinkedList method?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I wonder how can I avoid SonarQube issue:

> Declarations should use Java collection interfaces such as "List"
>   rather than specific implementation classes such as "LinkedList"

when I want to use specific method of LinkedList in code like this:

```
LinkedList<String> items = new LinkedList<String>();
//add someitems
String elem = items.removeFirst();
```

The only solution which I found is to change for Queue, but then I need also use methods of interface:

```
Queue<String> items = new LinkedList<String>();
//add someitems
String elem = items.poll();
```

I can also cast object before using this method. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You should know better than the tool. If you consider it normal, in this case, to depend on LinkedList rather than List, then simply ignore the warning. The tool is there to help you, not vice-versa.

Comment: These advice are heuristic at the end of the day. I would agree that the tool is not good and that it is too agressive.

Comment: List<String> blam = new LinkedList<String>();

Comment: @JBNizet The questions are legit nonetheless: Why is the tool raising a warning ? is it legit ? how should I fix it ?

Comment: @DwB List does not define the removeFirst() method.

Answer (score 3):

In this very case, the recommandation would be to use the interface from which this method is defined, as specified in the JavaDoc of [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirst()) : `removeFirst` comes from the interface [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and this is the interface you should probably be using rather than working  directly with the implementation.